# How can I bootstrap a CI in R for likelihood ratio? (sensitivity / 1 - specificity)

Tags: r, bootstrap, simulation

I have a test that attempts to classify samples as positive cases or negative cases based on a score. We can somewhat vary the score's threshold for what we call a positive or a negative case to achieve our desired test characteristics (sensitivity, specificity, which are used to calculate likelihood ratio).

A simple drawing is shown here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLpK9.jpg

I need to figure out how to get a confidence interval for the likelihood ratio.

I know bootstrapping is how to do this, but how exactly? Let's say I have 100 samples already. Should I just sample say 30 of them 1000 times and see what the distribution of likelihood ratios is? How exactly do I set this up? I need to somehow say "sample 30, make 2x2 table based on these 30 samples, calculate sensitivity and specificity and then likelihood ratio, store as likelihood ratio 1. Do this 999 more times".

Comment: The standard way of doing bootstrap would involve sampling 100 observations (critical: WITH replacement)  and repeating that many times (1000 may or may not be enough). On each of the 1000 samples, calculate your quantity of interest. Then you have a sampling distribution of your quantity of interest. I’m not sure why you’d sample only 30.

Comment: Got it. So if I have 100 samples of real data, I grab 100 samples (with replacement) from the original sample, and do this 1000 times?

Comment: Precisely! But definitely remember to do it with replacement.